# Negative argument to a C program in execl detected as an option

Tags: c, floating-point, arguments

I use the `execl()` function with that call:

```
execl("/localhome/globususer/mandel", "-b", xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, "-f", name, (char*)NULL);
```

All the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax are initialized by:

```
sprintf(xmin, "%f", (double)(XPOS - realmargin));
sprintf(xmax, "%f", (double)(XPOS + realmargin));
sprintf(ymin, "%f", (double)(YPOS - realmargin));
sprintf(ymax, "%f", (double)(YPOS + realmargin));
```

In the targeted program (/localhome/globususer/mandel), xmin and ymin are detected as options since they are negative numbers.
So `getopt()` detects "-0" on their values, and raises an error.

However, a direct call from the command line such as:

```
./mandel -b -0.452902 0.456189 0.367922 1.277013 -f /localhome/globususer/mandel.ppm
```

is correctly understood by the program.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You' re using `execl()` incorrectly. You should set `arg0` to the name of the executable:

```
execl("/localhome/globususer/mandel",
      "/localhome/globususer/mandel",
      "-b",
      xmin, 
      xmax, 
      ymin, 
      ymax, 
      "-f", 
      name, 
      NULL);
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec):

> The **`const char *arg`** and subsequent ellipses in the **`execl()`**, **`execlp()`**, and **`execle()`** functions can be thought of as *arg0, arg1, ..., argn*. Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.

When `mandel` runs `getopt()` with your original argument list, it skips over the `-b` (since it's in `argv[0]`, and it thinks that's the executable path name), and therefore starts parsing the args with the number (`-0.452902` in your example) instead of the `-b`. That makes it interpret the `-0` as an option, and you're out of luck.